# Get Week Of The Year

Tags: delphi, monthcalendar

Delphi Xe, Win 7, System TimeZone UTC+4:0, The first day of week in system - Monday, Time is synchronised with time.windows.com

In a palette of standard components Delphi Win32 there is component MonthCalendar, at it property WeekNubers=true (display of numbers of weeks), date=now, the first day - Monday.

Shows on 19 number (today) - number of week 43.

I request number through dateutils.WeekOfTheYear(now) = returns 42.

[image]

Source (0.5 Mb) http://www.sendspace.com/file/yuz6ko

Judging by an initial code of component MonthCalendar - there like all it is true (even if not to expose the first day of week, it takes value from system parametres).

And in inquiry WeekOfTheYear it is told, that all is considered also standard ISO applied, but numbers do not coincide :(

In any way I will not understand, where one week disappears - if to look on a calendar, should be 43 and if to consider, that weeks 53 and the first concerns last year...

By the way WeekOfTheYear on 01.01.2011 too returns 52 though like should return 1...

Why distinctions and where it is correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both results are correct, the difference is because the [`DateUtils.WeekOfTheYear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.WeekOfTheYear) function  uses the **ISO 8601** standard definition of a week. `That is, a week is considered to start on a Monday and end on a Sunday.`

Check this [explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) about the Weeks Numbers in the ISO 8601 format.

> If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in
>   week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in
>   week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00). 28 December
>   is always in the last week of its year.

Also the Embarcadero online help  for the [`DateUtils.WeekOfTheYear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.WeekOfTheYear) function says

> ....if the first calendar day of the year is a Friday, Saturday, or
>   Sunday, then for the first three, two, or one days of the calendar
>   year, WeekOfTheYear returns the last week of the previous year.
>   Similarly, if the last calendar day of the year is a Monday, Tuesday,
>   or Wednesday, then for the last one, two, or three days of the
>   calendar year, WeekOfTheYear returns 1 (the first week of the next
>   calendar year).

So due which the 01-01-2011 was Saturday this week is considered the week number 52 of the previous year.

And that also explains why the week number returned for today (19-10-2011) is 42 instead of 43.

Comment: The `MonthCalendar` component is based in the windows month calendar control and calculates the week number based in the value which you pass to the `FirstDayofWeek` property.

Comment: I have written, that in MonthCalendar Monday is registered by the first (I tried to insert and by default: values in system - too Monday in options Date and Time Windows), however values returns the different. In the inquiry I read about ISO the standard, like all should work correctly in both cases, I do not understand, why the different :(

Comment: Do you want which the `MonthCalendar` component shows the same week number, that is returned by the `WeekOfTheYear` function?

Comment: Yes, I have added a sreen and a source code in a question, look please

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I could see no difference between the week numbers in the `TMonthCalendar` component and those returned by `DateUtils.WeekOfTheYear()`. (Monday is the first day of week on my system.) Both show `42` for the current week and **`52`** (not `53`) for the week of `2011-01-01`. (It's `53` for `2010-01-01`, so maybe you just mixed that up.)

Now, as to why it's `52` or `53`, but not `1`, well, it's according to the [definition of the first week by ISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> First week is the week with the year's first Thursday in it.

So week number 1 in 2011 starts on `2011-01-03`, and the previous one belongs to the previous ISO year.

Comment: Yes, with 53 typing error, already brains boil. Has corrected on 52

Answer (score 2):

The `TMonthCalendar` can treat the last week of the year as the first week of the next year, `WeekOfTheYear` function does not do it, hence the difference.

For example according to `TMonthCalendar`, `1 Jan 2012` belongs to both last week of 2011 and first week of 2012; `2 Jan 2012` is the first day of the **second** week of 2012.
According `WeekOfTheYear` function,  `1 Jan 2012` belongs to the last week of 2011 only; `2 Jan 2012` is the first day of the **first** week of 2012.

Monday is the first day of the week for me.